# How to get a font's name and its styles?

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I have two Comboboxes: `[_cmbxFontName, _cmbxStyleName]`

I can load all installed fonts into `_cmbxFontName`, but I could not load fonts styles. If I select a font name in `_cmbxFontName`, then the other `_cmbxstyleName` combobox wants to load its styles. for example" [Regular, Normal, Bold, Italic, etc].

I know all fonts have different styles but how can I find and load them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the System.Drawing.FontStyle enumeration to list the styles. I think you can specify any style in FontStyle for any font when the font is created.

```
New Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
```

You can load the font styles into a combo box like this:

```
Dim styles() As FontStyle
Dim style As FontStyle

styles = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(FontStyle))
For Each style In styles
  combobox1.items.add(style.ToString)
Next style
```